# can a New-Module return a psobject?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

This module below  returns a empty object . Any suggestions to fix it ?

```
New-Module -ScriptBlock { 
    $resourcesDirectory="AA"
    .....
    $commonProperties = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ResourcesDirectory = $resourcesDirectory
    }

    return $commonProperties 
} -name GetXXX
```

Comment: Everything is a psobject

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for his help.</sup>

[`New-Module`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849740.aspx) by default returns the newly created module, as a `[System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo]` instance.

By "returns an empty object" I presume you mean that **your intent is to have your module *export* the `$commonProperties` *variable*** (which happens to contain a `[pscustomobject]` instance, but that is incidental), yet your code failed to do so.

The reason is that **in the absence of [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) calls, *variables* and *aliases* - unlike *functions* - are *not* automatically exported from a module**.

**Caveats**:

- If one or more `Export-ModuleMember` calls *are* present, *only* the specified members are exported (nothing is exported automatically).
- `Export-ModuleMember` calls are **best placed *at the bottom* of your module** definition, because they must come *after* the definitions of the elements to export themselves.
- If you want to limit the set of exported members that are imported into the current session to a *subset* of the module's *functions*, you can use `New-Module`'s `-Function` parameter.

  - If the module is used in the current session only, there's no point in combining `New-Module -Function` with `Export-ModuleMember`; also note that using `-Function` will prevent non-function members from being imported into the current session.
  - Combined with the default exporting behavior, `New-Module -Function` *effectively* provides an alternative to using an explicit `Export-ModuleMember` call with the function names inside the script block, though it's important to understand that the two mechanisms differ.

**To export variable `$commonProperties`, you need to call `Export-ModuleMember -Variable commonProperties`** (note the required absence of prefix `$` from the variable name):

```
$newModule = New-Module -ScriptBlock { 
    $resourcesDirectory="AA"
    $commonProperties = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ResourcesDirectory = $resourcesDirectory
    }

    # You must explicitly export variable $commonProperties.
    # Note that `Export-ModuleMember` must generally come *after* the 
    # definition of the variable, and that the variable name 
    # must not be $-prefixed.
    Export-ModuleMember -Variable commonProperties

    # (No need to `return` anything from the script block.
    #  Any output will be ignored.)
} -name GetXXX
```

Given that `New-Module` not only creates a new module but automatically imports it, `$commonProperties` is now available in the current session.

---

**Side notes**:

By adding switch **`-ReturnResult`**, you can tell `New-Module` to **return your *script block's output*** rather than the newly created module object (but the module is still imported into the current session).

Applied to your code that would return the *value* of variable `$commonProperties`, due to the `return $commonProperties` statement, but, as stated, your script block does not *export* any members, so the current session wouldn't see the `$commonProperties` *variable*.

---

Alternatively, switch **`-AsCustomObject`** tells `New-Module` to **return a `[pscustomobject]` instance whose members are the exported members**.
Note that normal export rules apply, and that a module is still being *created* behind the scenes, although it isn't *imported*.

Applied to your (corrected) code, with exported function `Foo` added:

```
$newObj = New-Module -ScriptBlock { 
    $resourcesDirectory="AA"
    $commonProperties = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ResourcesDirectory = $resourcesDirectory
    }
    function Foo { "I'm here." }
    Export-ModuleMember -Variable commonProperties -Function Foo
} -AsCustomObject
```

`$newObj` now contains a property named `commonProperties` that references the `$commonProperty` variable from the new (hidden) module's script block.

<sup>Note: `Get-Member` misleadingly reports this property's type as `NoteProperty`, suggesting a *static* value, whereas an exported function can potentially alter the value of the underlying variable (although that strikes me as an exotic case).  The true type is `[System.Management.Automation.PSVariableProperty]`, as `$newObj.psobject.properties['commonProperties'].GetType().FullName` reveals, whereas a true `NoteProperty` member has type `[System.Management.Automation.PSNoteProperty]`.</sup>

Similarly, the exported *function* `Foo` surfaces as a `ScriptMethod`-type member (method) that operates in the context of the new (hidden) module and sees *its* variables.
(As an aside: `$newObj.Foo.Script.Module` can be used to gain access to the hidden module.)

By contrast, exported *aliases* are seemingly *ignored*.

*Caveat*: Do not export members of different types by the same name (e.g., do not define a function and variable of the same name), as only one of them will be accessible.

Comment: +1 this answer since it highlights my response, you are not exporting anything. Either export explicitly, or use the -function argument.

Comment: @ConradB: Thanks. I just substantially rewrote the answer to (hopefully) make it more useful; thanks for the `-Function` parameter hint, I've incorporated it into the answer.

Comment: *Alternatively, switch -AsCustomObject tells New-Module not to actually create and import a module* Yes, module not imported, but it still need to be created. `(New-Module { function f { } } -AsCustomObject).f.Script.Module`

Comment: Also note that exported variables is not mere `NoteProperty`. `$co=New-Module { function Increment { (++$script:Value) } $Value=0; Export-ModuleMember -Function Increment -Variable Value } -AsCustomObject; $co.PSObject.Properties['Value'].GetType().FullName`. Them do not have their own value, but link back to exported variable: `$co.Value=123; $co.Increment(); $co.Value`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Thanks again, excellent background info - answer updated again.